# uso de python+csv en anacondas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, anaconda

estoy empezando a estudar python iba bien hasta que me tope con este error, intento seguir los pasos del tutorial, pero por alguna razon no me toma el archivo, subo lo que ingreso y a continuacion lo que me larga como error, ya intente poner el archivo en el disco C y es lo mismo.
esto ingreso siguiendo los pasos del tutorial:
#importacion de un archivo
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("G:/Programa programa/4.0_python/modulo_4/AB_NYC_2019", sep=",")

esto me salta al intentar ejecutar :
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[25], line 3
1 #importacion de un archivo
2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 df = pd.read_csv("G:/Programa programa/4.0_python/modulo_4/AB_NYC_2019", sep=",")

```
        File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:211, in deprecate_kwarg. 
        <locals>._deprecate_kwarg.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
       209     else:
       210         kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
        --> 211 return func(*args, **kwargs)

           File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:331, in 
         deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
      325 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
      326     warnings.warn(
      327         msg.format(arguments=_format_argument_list(allow_args)),
      328         FutureWarning,
       329         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
      330     )
      --> 331 return func(*args, **kwargs)

       File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:950, in 
      read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, 
       prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, 
    skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, 
      verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, 
    dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, 
     quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, 
      error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, 
      float_precision, storage_options)
      935 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
      936     dialect,
      937     delimiter,
     (...)
      946     defaults={"delimiter": ","},
      947 )
      948 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
      --> 950 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

      File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:605, in 
     _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
     602 _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
     604 # Create the parser.
     --> 605 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
     607 if chunksize or iterator:
     608     return parser

     File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1442, in 
      TextFileReader.__init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
      1439     self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
      1441 self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
      -> 1442 self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)

      File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1735, in 
       TextFileReader._make_engine(self, f, engine)
       1733     if "b" not in mode:
        1734         mode += "b"
      -> 1735 self.handles = get_handle(
       1736     f,
       1737     mode,
       1738     encoding=self.options.get("encoding", None),
       1739     compression=self.options.get("compression", None),
       1740     memory_map=self.options.get("memory_map", False),
       1741     is_text=is_text,
       1742     errors=self.options.get("encoding_errors", "strict"),
       1743     storage_options=self.options.get("storage_options", None),
       1744 )
       1745 assert self.handles is not None
       1746 f = self.handles.handle

       File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py:856, in get_handle(path_or_buf, 
       mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
       851 elif isinstance(handle, str):
       852     # Check whether the filename is to be opened in binary mode.
       853     # Binary mode does not support 'encoding' and 'newline'.
       854     if ioargs.encoding and "b" not in ioargs.mode:
       855         # Encoding
       --> 856         handle = open(
       857             handle,
       858             ioargs.mode,
       859             encoding=ioargs.encoding,
       860             errors=errors,
       861             newline="",
       862         )
       863     else:
       864         # Binary mode
       865         handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)

        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'G:/Programa 
         programa/4.0_python/modulo_4/AB_NYC_2019'
```

ya descargue el archivo varias veces , ya probe que todo estuviera conectado y funcionando con otros ejercicios y no saltaba ningun error.agradezco cualquier ayuda!!!!!

Comment: Debes agregar la extensión del archivo. Debe ser `G:/Programa programa/4.0_python/modulo_4/AB_NYC_2019.csv`

Comment: hola, gracias por responder, probe y ahora me larga este mensaje UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 54: invalid start byte

Comment: Ese error sucede en resumidas cuentas cuando Python no logra interpretar un caracter del archivo. Cómo se ve el csv al abrirlo con un editor de texto plano (como el bloc de notas)? Todo normal o aparece algún caracter raro?

Comment: esta como en un lenguaje antiguo, la verdad indescifrable.crei que colocando el vsc se solucionaria, pero despues de esto de utf salto de nuevo el mismo error del principio. la abri en excel para ver si se abria bien, y me larga que presenta error, que si quiero corregirlo, le doy a aceptar pero aun asi me toma mal el archivo,seguire buscando soluciones pero tambien vere si puedo contactarme con los responsables, tal vez este mal subido el archivo

Comment: Cuando se ven un monton de caracteres raros "al azar", es por que el editor hace lo que puede para interpretar el archivo como texto plano (el csv es texto plano) y ese es el resultado. Estás segura de que lo que descargaste realmente es un csv? Ten en cuenta que cambiarle la extensión a un archivo no cambia realmente el tipo de archivo del que se trata. Si me podés pasar la pagina donde lo descargás, podría ver mejor que está pasando, si no no hay problema.

Answer (score 0):

:
Por si todavia tienen este problema,Este error es por que el archivo esta corrupto:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'G:/Programa programa/4.0_python/modulo_4/AB_NYC_2019'
Busca y vas ver que el peso del archivo original deberia ser 6900 y el q intentas subir 4888 es por q esta roto, busca el archivo en la web y proba otra vez, consejo tb proba bajando un .csv de prueba e intenta abrirlo, yo perdi tres dias enteros tratando de resolverlo, instale e instale python, anaconda todo , y era eso el archivo roto, espero te sirva saludos!
https://github.com/erkansirin78/datasets/blob/7a4ab031d4c1ad1298904a1d0410001dc1631060/AB_NYC_2019.csv
búscalo ahí a ver si ese te abre .